# Getting lint out of a 2 inch drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, clog

I have a 2 inch drain that serves both a sink and combination washer/dryer.  It has a near horizontal section and a couple of 90 degree elbows, and I fear that that section is filling with a toxic combination of lint and grease.

Most of the time the sink drains fine.

When the washer runs, the first batch of water seems to rehydrate the lint, and the second rinse cycle backs up into the sink, bringing particles of food and other nasty stuff back up.

I've tried snaking it, using drain cleaners, plunging it, dumping boiling water down it, treating it with enzymes, etc, and the problem seems to recur.

- Are there drain pigs similar to pipeline pigs?
- If I can somehow get a drain snake to a cleanout in the basement, are there brushes or other tools that could be used to clean out the horizontal sections of the pipes?
- Is there anything else that can clean accumulated lint embedded in grease out?
- Do drain bladders work on these kinds of obstructions, even from far away?

Comment: Do you clean it and then 'x' months later the problem happens again? Or do you clean it and it happens again the very next time you run the washing machine? Big difference and will affect the answer.

Comment: *"a toxic combination of lint and grease"* Is a bit dramatic, unless you are running the waste from your meth lab down this drain to toxify it. It's likely a perfectly ordinary "gross, disgusting, but won't kill you if you don't go and eat it, and possibly not even then" collection of lint and grease and hair and soap scum and...well, I suppose some toxic drain cleaners, now.

Comment: What is the measured slope of "near horizontal" - that might need to be corrected. Were proper DWV sweeps used, or improper tight elbows? What's the pipe material? Please [edit] to add details (and pictures, ideally) Where's the vent at?

Comment: I haven't found the exact slope (pipe is buried in a wall/ceiling), and I don't know exactly if there is a vent.  There is a sink on the top floor, and a sink on the next floor down that ties into the same line. 

In general, if everything is dry, it works fine for a while.  After the lint has been soaked for a while, the problems recur.